# What's the fastest way to threshold a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want the resulting array as a binary yes/no.

I came up with

```
    img = PIL.Image.open(filename)

    array = numpy.array(img)
    thresholded_array = numpy.copy(array)

    brightest = numpy.amax(array)
    threshold = brightest/2

    for b in xrange(490):
        for c in xrange(490):
            if array[b][c] > threshold:
                thresholded_array[b][c] = 255
            else:
                thresholded_array[b][c] = 0

    out=PIL.Image.fromarray(thresholded_array)
```

but iterating over the array one value at a time is very very slow and I know there must be a faster way, what's the fastest?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of looping, you can compare the entire array at once in several ways.  Starting from

```
>>> arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, (3,3))
>>> brightest = arr.max()
>>> threshold = brightest // 2
>>> arr
array([[214, 151, 216],
       [206,  10, 162],
       [176,  99, 229]])
>>> brightest
229
>>> threshold
114
```

Method #1: use `np.where`:

```
>>> np.where(arr > threshold, 255, 0)
array([[255, 255, 255],
       [255,   0, 255],
       [255,   0, 255]])
```

Method #2: use boolean indexing to create a new array

```
>>> up = arr > threshold
>>> new_arr = np.zeros_like(arr)
>>> new_arr[up] = 255
```

Method #3: do the same, but use an arithmetic hack

```
>>> (arr > threshold) * 255
array([[255, 255, 255],
       [255,   0, 255],
       [255,   0, 255]])
```

which works because `False == 0` and `True == 1`.

---

For a 1000x1000 array, it looks like the arithmetic hack is fastest for me, but to be honest I'd use `np.where` because I think it's clearest:

```
>>> %timeit np.where(arr > threshold, 255, 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop
>>> %timeit up = arr > threshold; new_arr = np.zeros_like(arr); new_arr[up] = 255;
100 loops, best of 3: 14.2 ms per loop
>>> %timeit (arr > threshold) * 255
100 loops, best of 3: 6.05 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if your tresholding operation is special, e.g. need to customize it for every pixel or something, but you can just use logical operation on a np.arrays. For example:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.round(np.random.rand(5,5)*255)

thresholded_array = a > 100; #<-- tresholding on 100 value

print(a)
print(thresholded_array)
```

Gives:

```
[[ 238.  201.  165.  111.  127.]
 [ 188.   55.  157.  121.  129.]
 [ 220.  127.  231.   75.   23.]
 [  76.   67.   75.  141.   96.]
 [ 228.   94.  172.   26.  195.]]

[[ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False False]
 [False False False  True False]
 [ True False  True False  True]]
```